# Jenkins calls batch file which needs windows environment variables. Bat file is uneditable

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins

Basically Jenkins is calling a bat file which is proprietary and does some compilation.

Calling the file directly from command prompt works fine. However when Jenkins calls the bat file  it cannot find environment variables it needs and an error is thrown that the value is unknown.

I know if I could edit the bat file I could circumvent the issue, but the file is proprietary so that is not an option. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using a declarative pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: Been a while since I used it (and Jenkins).*

Back in the day we did this with the [EnvInject](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/) plugin. Worked quite well as far as I remember it.

[image]

Comment: that does not seem to be doing the trick

Comment: @EdwinFairchild Are you using pipelines and have you read [this](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/#plugin-content-jenkins-pipeline-compatibility)?